# Is it possible to make a convolution layer probabilistic with Tensorflow Probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

In a tutorial on Regression with Probabilistic Layers in TensorFlow Probability, it set up the following model:

```
model = tfk.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1 + 1),
  tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
      lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t[..., :1],
                           scale=1e-3 + tf.math.softplus(0.05 * t[..., 1:]))),
])
```

My question is, it is possible to do the same with convolution layers? For example, in 3D segmentation the output layer has shape (3, 128, 128, 128). How can I make the last layer (or logits) probabilistic as above? If I flatten the last layer, then the dimension is: `3*128*128*128` which results in a resource exhausted error.

Comment: You can just use `tfpl.OneHotCategorical()`. I can give an example if you provide more info (how many classes you have etc.)

Comment: I am using a unet and the output shape is (3, 128,128,128). I am using sigmoid activation (not softmax) because the classes overlap and and 3 is the number of classes. In the penultimate layer I have: `output_layer= Conv3D(n_labels, (1, 1, 1), padding='same')(current_layer)`, which I then pass through sigmoid. I was wondering if I can make the last layer probabilistic, so that I can sample from the last layer to get multiple segmentation maps. I don't quite understand how to make layers probabilistic with Conv3D in the last layer (may be the logit layer before sigmoid).

Comment: @Frightera I tried to implement a probabilistic layer with MixtureSameFamily. I have 3 output nodes  for 3 classes(one vs all), and before passing through sigmoid I want each output to be a Mixture of 2 Gaussians (+ve class and -ve). Can you please have a look at it as soon as possible? Thank You so much. Here's the link to the Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15Xy9Hj-BTdoMVWtPntMlm4Hb8jvl0BVJ?usp=sharing

Comment: That can work. If I were you, I would use Conv3DFlipout layers and 3DUpsampling instead of deconvolution. There should be no issues with `channels_first` in Flipout layers since new tfp version is released. Or one can use the experimental layer https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/experimental/nn/ConvolutionTransposeVariationalFlipout

Comment: Can you MixtureSameFamily with a batch size 7 or 1?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Training batch size is 1. The errors arise from MixturesSameFamily. Yeah I am using Conv3DFlipout layers and 3DUpsampling in my work. In colab, is a close example to my work where I am trying to use a probabilistic layer in my last layer to map a 3 mixture distributions (1 for each class).

Comment: In Colab you set the batch size to 5. In your work, you set batch size to 1?

Comment: @Frightera yeah one image at a time. Whenever I tried to run a mixture model,  I get an 'unable to broadcast' error. I thought its because the data is channels first format. Also, If I want to have 3 separate mixtures with 2 mixture components in each node, then the [event_shape] in the distribution is 2 and distribution [batch_size]=3?

Comment: @Frightera can you please help with this question related to `Convolution3DReparameterization()`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69720260/changing-the-default-prior-and-posterior-in-tensorflow-probability-convolution3d